# Creating a Table called PRESENTER -- Encountering ERROR ORA-00907

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE PRESENTER(
PresenterNo VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
PresenterName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
Biography VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
InstitutionName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
CONTRAINT labPK PRIMARY KEY (PresenterNo));
```

Having following error:

Error starting at line : 4 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE PRESENTER(
PresenterNo VARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
PresenterName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
Biography VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
InstitutionName VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
CONTRAINT labPK PRIMARY KEY (PresenterNo))
Error report -
```

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:
*Action:

Comment: Typo? Should be `ConStraint`.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the `CONSTRAINT` keyword. Correct way is down below.

```
CREATE TABLE PRESENTER
(
   PresenterNo       VARCHAR2 (9) NOT NULL,
   PresenterName     VARCHAR2 (45) NOT NULL,
   Biography         VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
   InstitutionName   VARCHAR2 (45) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT labPK PRIMARY KEY (PresenterNo)
)
```